# How to drop columns of a data.frame with NA condition {dplyr package} or {base}

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

My problem: a large dataset with columns containing very few values.

What I whish: dropping columns of the data.frame  containing a frequency of missing values with  **dplyr** package (or base).

What I tried:

```
 # my data.frame
 data <- data.frame(column1 = c(1, 2, 13, 4),
                    column2 = c(4, NA, 9, 1),
                    column3 = c(12, NA, NA, 78)) 

  # relative frequency of NA values
  missing_values <- colMeans(is.na(data))

  # selecting columns
  library(dplyr)

  complete_table <- data %>%
                   select (missing_values>0.25)
```

Comment: `data[missing_values < 0.25]`?

Comment: `data %>% select(which(missing_values>0.25))` if you want to use dplyr

Comment: My question was about using dplyr. Is it really fully duplicate?